# How to sort 'find' results in bash by size

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, find, pipe

I am wondering if there's an "easy" way (through a pipe or something) to order (by file size) the results of a "find" command in bash such as:

```
find /location/of/directory/ -type f -size +2G
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%k` for example to print the size in kilobytes:

```
find . -type f -size +2G -printf "%kKB %p\n" | sort -n
```

- By saying `-printf "%kKB %p\n"` you are printing the file in kilobytes and then the name.
- `sort -n` gets this input and sorts it accordingly.

See an example:

```
$ find . -type f -size +1M -printf "%p %kKB\n" | sort -n -k2
./arrr.txt.gz 1664KB
./brrr.gz 32388KB
```

Comment: Nice solution using `printf` in `find`. Don't know when will Apple add it on OSX (BSD) find :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

`find /location/of/directory/ -type f -size +2G  -exec du -s {} + |sort -n`

`-exec` executes command `du -s` on each search result and  and `sort -n` sorts the result numerically.

Comment: thanks @RBH for this! it works well and is a solution to my original post, but the other answer leads to more flexibility and is ultimately more useful for me.